# How can I handle a TCA multi select like a inline field in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

Maybe my question sounds a little bit weird. So here are the details:

I have created the two classes "Position" and "Step". Furthermore every step can contain positions. My tables and the relevant fields looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_foxexample_domain_model_step (
    ...
    positions int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE tx_foxexample_domain_model_position (
   ...
   step int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   ...
);
```

I think it is a normal 1:n relation, because each step can store n-positions and every position could be part of only one step.

My classes and the relevant properties looks like the following:

```
class Step extends AbstractEntity
{
    ...
    /**
     * Positions
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Fox\FoxExample\Domain\Model\Position>
     * @cascade remove
     */
     protected $positions = null;
     ...
}

class Position extends AbstractEntity
{
   ...
   /**
    * Stores the relation to step
    *
    * @var \Fox\FoxExample\Domain\Model\Step
    */
    protected $step = null;
   ...
}
```

The step stores n-positions in a object storage property and the position just stores the relevant step in a step property.

So far I have created a position or some positions for a step directly inline via the inline field, the TCA for my step was like the following:

```
...
'positions' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '...',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'inline',
         'foreign_table' => 'tx_foxexample_domain_model_position',
         'foreign_field' => 'step',
         'maxitems' => 50,
         'appearance' => array(
             'collapseAll' => 1,
             'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
             'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
             'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
             'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
         ),
    ),
),
...
```

So the positions and step relations were correctly saved into database, but for some reasons I have changed a lot and it is not necessary anymore to create the positions inside the steps because the positions already exists and a user have to select the positions which are necessary. So I changed the inline type to a multi select field:

```
'positions' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '...',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
         'foreign_table' => 'tx_foxexample_domain_model_position',
         'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY title ASC',
         'minitems' => 0,
         'maxitems' => 50,
    ),
 ),
```

With this changes a user can select the relevant positions for each step, but if I take a look at the database tables I can see that the step field of my positions table is always 0 and the positions field of my step table holds the position uid now.

So I run into some trouble because I can't define a 'foreign_field' for the multi select field, so the relation to the position table is gone. Furthermore I can only add one position because only one position will be saved and the other selected positions will be ignored because only one uid will be stored.

Before save:
[image]

After save:
[image]

In summary I want to keep the inline field behaviour for the multi select field. What can I do to keep the inline field behaviour for a multi select field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a MM-Table because a step can have multiple positions and a position can be assigned in multiple steps. I'd suggest to introduce a table `tx_foxexample_step_position_mm`:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_foxexample_step_position_mm (
  uid_local int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  uid_foreign int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  sorting int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

  KEY uid_local (uid_local),
  KEY uid_foreign (uid_foreign)
);
```

You tell your TCA to use it (rest stays the same):

```
'positions' => array(
    'config' => array(
         'MM' => 'tx_foxexample_step_position_mm'
    ),
 ),
```

Now you need to migrate the existing data to the new structure. I suggest writing a CommandController that populates the MM-table with the current relations.

Comment: It works with a mm-table, but is there a way to avoid that positions could be used in multiple steps? Because I don't want that a position is reused in a another step. I thought I could extend the 'foreign_table_where' like "AND step = 0 ORDER BY title ASC", but this field is always zero.

Comment: So I want a 1:n relation with a multiselect field is this not possible?